# Codeigniter: Single Post is Not Shown

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to create a simple blog with a beginner's knowledge of Codeigniter. I have been able to loop all the blog posts in the index page. But when i try to open a single post it doesn't show up. Even though things seem correct to me so far.

Model:

```
function get_post($postID) {
            $this->db->select()->from('posts')->where(array('active'=>1, 'postID'=> 'postID'))->order_by('date_added', 'desc');
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->first_row('array');
        }
```

Controller:

```
   function post($postID) {
        $data['posts']= $this->post->get_post($postID);
        $this->load->view('post',$data);
    }
```

View:

```
    <?php 
            if (!isset($post)) { ?>
            <p>This was accessed incorrectly</p>
            <?php } else { ?>

            <h2><?= $post['title']; ?></h2>
            <p><?= $post['post']; ?></p>
        <?php } ?>
```

The single page shows "This was accessed incorrectly". Here is the blog link **[blog link](http://orbitwebsolution.net/test/)**. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably the "typo" in:

```
$data['posts']= $this->post->get_post($postID);
```

see here you use  `posts` (many) and then you try to access it with `$post`. So just change it to:

```
$data['post']= $this->post->get_post($postID);
```

and it should be fixed

---

### **UPDATE**

Also in the `model` you have:

```
$this->db->select()->from('posts')->where(array('active'=>1, 'postID'=> 'postID'))->order_by('date_added', 'desc');
```

where you use `'postID'=> 'postID'` the second part should be the variable `$postID`:

```
$this->db->select()->from('posts')->where(array('active'=>1, 'postID'=> $postID))->order_by('date_added', 'desc');
```

Comment: Do a `<?php print_r($post); ?>` in your view. http://orbitwebsolution.net/test/posts/post/5 here it works?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just need to be careful during type. I appreciate your help. Have a wonderful time!